# Right query to select all messages from friends in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, optimization

I have a Facebook like wall stream. So the wall items must be friend related with reverse chronological ordering.
To map that, I have 2 tables : wall_items(id, user_id, [...], created) and user_friends(id, from_user_id, to_user_id) with index on each specified attributes.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM wall_items
    INNER JOIN user_friends ON user_friends.from_user_id = wall_items.user_id AND user_friends.to_user_id = "{id of user from whose I want the wall stream}"
ORDER BY wall_items.created DESC
```

It's sometimes quick, sometimes slow, depending on how much item I have for the specified user (less is better). I assumed it was because of a bad index selection from MySQL so I added :

```
FORCE INDEX (created)
```

and now it's the opposite, the more items I have, faster the request will be.

If I use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, it's fast in all case but this is not what I want...

Have you some ideas ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are a bit stuffed with this one.
Your first attempt was slower for more records because the order by clause added an in memory sort.

Second got rid of that by using the index, but now it's doing a serial read over that and the checking to see if the rest of the criteria match up.

A sideways thought, what about some sort of date range ie recent messages from my friends...

So the further you go back the longer it takes, but there's an implicit expectation that it will...

Comment: That's something I was thinking about, but the user is quite new and don't have so much friends, he will have less items then someone who have many friends ; maybe too little to cover his wall... Is there no way to use the index for the JOIN **AND** for the ORDER BY ?